# Using X25-E SSD on Dell R710 w/PERC H700

Tags: ssd, dell-perc

I noticed that StackExchange/ServerFault is using a Dell R710 with PERC H700 controller and Intel X25-E SSDs for a database server.  We're trying to do the same thing!

We're currently running the most current PERC firmware, version 12.10.1 (which unfortunately is several releases behind the equivalent LSI firmware).  The Intel X25-E SSDs run beautifully in all respects--configuration, performance, etc.

What we're seeing is two effects--about two minutes after a reboot, the disk status lights permanently turn from green to blinking amber, and at the same time, the hardware management log gets a non-critical error with "A non-Dell supplied disk drive has been detected".  These seem to be more of a nuisance than anything else.

At this point I'm about ready to get some tape and cover the lights.  So my question to the StackExchange/ServerFault folks (or anybody else) is whether they ran into anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

We have not seen any thing like that. They might have introduced that in the `12.10.1` version of the firmware thought. Our servers are currently on `12.10.0`

Dell really doesn't like you running disks that arn't provided by them.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense, and not from a "we just want more money" perspective. Dell warranties the whole server, and when you insert a non-Dell-supplied component, tracking down problems is difficult. If you started having RAID controller issues, for example, Dell might make you remove the third-party disks/SSDs and reproduce the issue with their disks in order to provide support. Dell has QAd specific drives with specific firmware versions only.

Almost all Tier-1 servers work exactly the same way. Some older HP and IBM servers simply wouldn't spin up third-party drives at all!

Comment: It does make sense from that perspective. However, Dell storage tends to be rather overpriced, and a lot of folks are well used to building and tinkering with their own machines. I think the option of buying storage seperately makes sense too. Each to their own and all that.